# How can I get YouTube to play at 2x speed in Firefox, in addition to Chrome?

Tags: youtube

It works on Chrome, but somehow it doesn't work on Firefox..

Comment: This is on-topic based on "Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play a YouTube video at twice its speed on Chrome because you're using an **HTML5 `<video>` player**. It's almost always automatic on Chrome because Chrome seems to support everything the player needs:

[image]

> HTMLVideoElement, H.264, WebM VP8, Media, Source Extensions, MSE & H.264, MSE & WebM VP9.

FireFox, on the other hand, only supports the first half:

[image]

Hence the player is rarely an HTML5 video object.

However, you can turn it on manually. Go to http://www.youtube.com/html5, and click on the blue **"Request the HTML5 player"** button:

[image]

You can later click "Use default player" if you have any problems. However, you should now be able to change the speed of most of your videos like in Chrome:

[image]